# Confused about reading from csv file in java

Tags: java, csv

So, I currently am doing a project where I'm creating a stocklist for a car dealership.
My intention was to have a csv file named Cars.csv in which the software reads from it and loads this into the GUI fields.

I'm really confused on how to read from this file, I want to directly access certain records. I understand it's a 2D array also. I'm just confused on how to set this whole thing up. My intention was to have a class named Cars also, and giving it attributes.

If anyone could advise me on anything please let me know. Please look at this image.
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki6ha.png)

I thought there would be a way to read it like row1, column4, just like an array.

Comment: maybe one of these 107 [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+csv+file+to+2d+array) will be of help?

Answer (score 1):

Approach should be as follows.

1. Try reading a file as an input stream into you application.
2. Read each line for that input stream.
3. Split that line using "," into an array.

This way you will be able to read the content of your CSV file into your application.

Let me show a sample code as well.

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file)
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader();

Map<String, String[]> lines = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] lineContent= line.split(",");
    // use this in the way you need
    lines.put(lineContent[0], lineContent);
}
```

Now when you want to get the line having "LA1 ABC"; you just need to invoke `lines.get("LA1 ABC")`.

Comment: With this method am I able to locate a certain record via direct access?
So I'd want to locate the colour of a LA1 ABC, and LA1 ABC is like the 5th row. 
How would I get this?

Comment: So we can create a Map with the first column as a key, and all the text as value array in the map. I updated the answer to show how that can be done.

Comment: @zayd1k - in short map is a key, value pair; where you can refer to some value using a key. In this case, we are storing the content of a row against the first column value. So if you know the first column data, you can quickly extract all the data from the map.

Comment: Can you have multiple values for one key in the HashMap?

Comment: In a map, the key is always unique; and there can be only one value against the key. But the good news is that value can be an object, so if you have multiple values better create an object or create a `List` to hold those data and use it as the value in key-value pair.

Comment: In such a situation the map can be something like `Map<String, List<Car>> lines = new HashMap<String, List<Car>>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use open source libraries to read the CSV files.
OpenCSV is one such library.

One blog which explaing how to use OpenCSV to read the CSV
https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv